# Why is there a definite article in the phrase "jump in the air"

Tags: definite-article

I must admit, that despite having spoken English for quite some time, i still cannot grasp all the intricacies of articles. My native tongue just doesn't have them, and they continue to perplex me.

The phrase "jump in the air" seems to stand out as something unusual. One is not jumping into the tank with some specific air, but instead is just jumping upwards, whatever air one meets there is quite irrelevant and unknown.

I have read [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106301/why-is-there-a-definite-article-in-the-idiom-adding-fuel-to-the-fire), which was very helpful, but i don't believe is relevant in this example. Would one consider "jump in the air" to be an idiom? If so, that would explain it.

Comment: [This answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/uses-of-the-definite-article-the-in-generic-noun-phrases/22650#22650) might help you some.

Comment: "Jump in the air" is not an idiomatic phrase, such as *fuel to the fire*.  Could you use your phrase in a sentence, or more than one, so we can better know how you think it is or should be used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are certain uncountable nouns used in idiomatic phrases that behave in this way. After all, we see similar wording with:

- swim in the ocean
- a stab in the dark
- bring home the bacon
- another one bites the dust
- turn up the volume
- hands in the air

However, I understand your confusion! After all, we [generally](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=swim+in+the+ocean%2Cswim+in+ocean%2C+best+of+luck%2C+best+of+the+luck&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) say:

- a moment in time (not *a moment in the time*)
- in sickness and in health (not *in the health*)
- bundle of joy (not *bundle of the joy*)
- best of luck (not *best of the luck*)
- taken with a grain of salt (not *with a grain of the salt*)

I can't think of a foolproof rule that would tell you when to include a definite article, and when to omit one. You're right to say that some of it is simply idiomatic – or at least seems to be. But do remember that you don't need to be talking about "some specific X" to use a definite article; that's only one use of a few. Oddly enough, when I say, "My daughter played the clarinet," we aren't talking about a specific clarinet; however, when we say, "My son ate the hamburger," we *are* likely talking about a specific hamburger (like the one you left on the counter, for example.) Here's another interesting one: if I say "Turn up the radio," then I'm referring to a specific radio; however, if I say, "This song got a lot of play on the radio," I'm *not* talking about a specific radio, but radio playlists in general.

Comment: Yes  but "jump in the air" is not an idiomatic phrase (it's not something native speakers would often say).

Comment: @AlanC - precisely why I elected to use _hands in the air_ in my list of examples instead. I don't think there's any need to get wrapped around the axle about the degree to which _jump in the air_ is idiomatic. The O.P.'s problem seems to be with the trickiness of articles in general, and I agree: that's a thorny problem for the learner.

Answer (score -2):

I don't agree with

"whatever air one meets there is quite irrelevant and unknown."

Whatever air you meet there is quite specific. It is the specific air you are jumping into. Just like *the ground* you land on is the specific ground that forms your landing place.

Otherwise, it is not really common to say *jump in the air*. So no, it's not at all an idiom or even an idiomatic expression. I don't know when I would say it; it would have to be in a specialized context.

A more useful and common phrase is

> jump into the water

and the water the person is jumping into is quite specific: the water that the person is, or will, or is being asked to jump into.

Comment: You take a breath of air, not a breath of the air though.

Comment: @v010dya most times, but not always. this stuff is highly context dependent.

Comment: @v010dya for instance: take a breath of the air in this room. doesn't it stink?

Comment: This is exactly what i'm saying, it's a breath of air, unless it's some specific air.

Comment: Do you deny that when you *jump into the water* you are jumping into "specific" water?